# How to have RTS units move along un-even terrain?

Tags: movement, terrain, rts

My current world is a flat `2D plane`.

I want to make the terrain 3D, like hills, bumps, etc. If I tell a unit to go to a position (x, y) in 2D, how do I make sure the unit is always at ground level?

For example, if `x, y` is above the current position in 3D?

I am defining terrain height using a height map, and generating a simple mesh from it. Path-finding will remain flat 2-d, and can project to 3-d.

Comment: How do you intend to define your terrain height? Are you using a heightmap, voxels, polygon terrain or perhaps something entirely different? The answer would depend on your preferred solution.

Comment: I am using a height-map, I have updated my question. I am new to map generation so I didn't think to include it.

Comment: It sounds like you could simply compare the adjacent (x,y) position's height against the height at your current position, and if it's above a threshold maximum increase/steepness, do not try to move there. But maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: I mean that if a unit moves to pos x,z, and the height at that position is different from the start, I dont want the unit to move in a straight line there, I want it to stay attached to the ground. Like on a sloping hill, direction from point A to B (bottom to top) is a straight line, but the unit would be flying then.

Comment: Would you not simply set the height of the unit to the height of the terrain under it after each step? Can you show us the code you're using and the "flying" artifact you're getting, so that we can help you debug it?

Comment: Thanks Gregory, I see now once again I have not asked a good question. I do not have a bug, but was asking more for the concept. Setting the heights of units manually is what I wanted to do, but my units can have force and velocity (like cavalry charges) in all three dimensions and that is what is tripping me up. If I simply set the heights, how does force factor in on the y-axis?